# How to access values from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Maybe I'm stupid asking this question but I need your help. I'm having problem access the second parameter of the return View.
I have this code below:

Model

```
public struct Hello
{
    public string Hi { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Hello> list = new List<Hello>();
    list.Add(new Hello() { Hi = "Test" });
    list.Add(new Hello() { Hi = "Test to display" });
    return View("Index", list);
}
```

How can I access the list variable in Index page? I want to enumerate the data.

I have this code in my `Index.cshtml` page:

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var x in list)
    {
        <li>@x</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to add `@model List<yourAssembly.Hello>` at the top of the view and use `@foreach (var x in Model) { <li>@x</li>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `View` is bind with list of type `Hello`.

```
@model List<MyNamespace.Hello>
```

then you can use it in your view like -

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        <li>@x.Hi</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Same answer with Sir Stephen Muecke. Thanks for the help. :)